# how to transform an array of integers into regions in perl?

Tags: perl

I now have an integer array like,
(1,13,3,5,6,7,11,10,8,2,12)
and I want to get the consecutive sub-regions form this array,
the results of above array should be (1,3), (5,8), (10,13)

The array maybe very large. Do anybody have any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why `5,8` and not `5,6`? Should list of numbers be sorted first?

Comment: @Сухой27: it seems fairly clear that the numbers should be sorted.

Comment: Could you post expected results for `(1,13,3,5,6,7,11,10,8,2,12,15,1)` as **valid** perl data structure? [Added "single number" range and a duplicate number (1)]

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip should be a list of arrays, (1,3), (5,8), (10,13), (15). Single number should be reserved and duplicated number is only counted once.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`Set::IntSpan`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan) module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use Set::IntSpan;

my @values = (1, 13, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10, 8, 2, 12);
my $set = Set::IntSpan->new(@values);
my @spans = $set->spans;

dd @spans;
```

#### Outputs:

```
([1, 3], [5, 8], [10, 13])
```

If a run contains only one number, the lower and upper bounds will be the same, e.g. `[42, 42]`.

### Performance

As salva pointed out in the comments, [`Set::IntSpan`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan) does not perform well with a large number of ranges. An alternative is [`Set::IntSpan::Fast`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan::Fast), which according to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan::Fast#Comparision-with-Set::IntSpan) uses binary searches and tends toward O log N performance. If you install [`Set::IntSpan::Fast::XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan::Fast::XS) as well, you will get even better performance (no need to change the `use` statement, the XS version will be used automatically if it's installed).

The following iterates through the ranges and pushes them onto an array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use Set::IntSpan::Fast;

my @values = (1, 13, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10, 8, 2, 12);
my $set = Set::IntSpan::Fast->new;
$set->add(@values);

my @ranges;
my $iter = $set->iterate_runs;
while (my ($from, $to) = $iter->()) {
    push @ranges, [ $from, $to ];
}

dd @ranges;
```

#### Outputs:

```
([1, 3], [5, 8], [10, 13])
```

Note that to do anything useful with the ranges, you'll have to iterate through this array; it would be more efficient to do the work as you iterate through the set the first time instead of iterating through two different structures.

Comment: Nice! First time seeiing this module. Always wondering how peoples knows (remembers) many thousands modules...

Comment: I happened to need this for something just last week.

Comment: Be aware that `Set::IntSpan` doesn't use any kind of indexing internally, so the performance degrades when the number of ranges grows (it is `O(N^2)`).

Comment: Hey, but then you have [Set::IntSpan::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan::Fast) which, the author claims, has the linear searchs removed.

Comment: @salva Good points, thanks. I added a `Set::IntSpan::Fast` solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using a hash, get some random element and look for consecutive elements both before and after:

```
my @ints = (...);
my %ints = map { $_ => 1 } @ints;
my @ranges;
while (keys %ints) {
  my $bottom = my $top = each %ints;
  delete $ints{$bottom};
  1 while (delete $ints{--$bottom});
  1 while (delete $ints{++$top});
  push @ranges, [$bottom + 1, $top - 1];
}
say join ', ', map "$_->[0]-$_->[1]", @ranges;
```

Comment: This is _uncomparable_ faster than Set::IntSpan.

Comment: @jm666, there is also Set::IntSpan::Fast and the XS version Set::IntSpan::Fast::XS that for large datasets is faster than my method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the job done well and quickly with minimal effort on your part, use [`Set::IntSpan`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Set%3A%3AIntSpan) as [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24997468/15168).

If you want a DIY job, then you can consider using this code as a basis:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$, = " ";

my @data = (1, 13, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10, 8, 2, 12);

sub pr_region
{
    my($lo, $hi) = @_;
    print "($lo";
    print ", $hi" if ($lo != $hi);
    print ")\n";
}

sub print_regions
{
    my(@data) = @_;
    print "Raw: ", @data, "\n";

    my @sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @data;
    #print "Sorted: ", @sorted, "\n";

    my $lo = $sorted[0];
    for my $i (1 .. scalar(@sorted)-1)
    {
        if ($sorted[$i-1] != $sorted[$i] - 1 &&
            $sorted[$i-1] != $sorted[$i])
        {
            pr_region($lo, $sorted[$i-1]);
            $lo = $sorted[$i];
        }
    }
    pr_region($lo, $sorted[$#sorted]);
}

print_regions(@data);
print_regions(1);
print_regions(1, 10);
print_regions(1, 2, 10);
print_regions(1, 9, 10);
print_regions(@data, 11, 3, 19, -3);
```

The output from it is:

```
Raw:  1 13 3 5 6 7 11 10 8 2 12 
(1, 3)
(5, 8)
(10, 13)
Raw:  1 
(1)
Raw:  1 10 
(1)
(10)
Raw:  1 2 10 
(1, 2)
(10)
Raw:  1 9 10 
(1)
(9, 10)
Raw:  1 13 3 5 6 7 11 10 8 2 12 11 3 19 -3 
(-3)
(1, 3)
(5, 8)
(10, 13)
(19)
```

I've made no effort at minimizing the code.  It prints its results rather than packaging them in a data structure for reuse.  It doesn't handle an empty array.